# loadjava utility for osx

Tags: oracle, macos, loadjava

Is there a loadjava utility for OSX or a way to load my java classes to Oracle database from mac os? I am trying to execute a java stored procedure using eclipse from mac os and I am not able to load my java classes into the Oracle database.

This is my java class

```
public class CallJava {
public static String welcome() {
    return "Welcome to Java";
}
}
```

and this is my sql query to invoke the java class

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION call_CallJava RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME'CallJava.welcome() return java.lang.String';
/
```

I am able to do it on the windows machine using the loadJava utility and my question is how can I do this on mac os.

Comment: What does Eclipse have to do with it? `loadjava` is a command-line interface.

Comment: Yes, how can I use loadjava which is a command-line interface from OSX?

Comment: I was trying to call the loadjava method from my eclipse java file. My question is how can I get the loadjava tool which is a command-line interface in mac os so that i can either call the method or use it from the console? The installation or the way to work with it in mac os

Comment: Do you need to use `loadjava`? Can you log onto the database and create the source files using `CREATE JAVA SOURCE`?

Comment: I am writing a java stored procedure and I need to publish my java stored procedure classes to the db. "Can you log into the database and create the source files using CREATE JAVA SOURCE" this would become meaningless - in this case oracle pl/sql stored procedure will suffice the need.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please provide a [MCVE] with an example of the procedure you are trying to create and how you are trying to invoke it.

Comment: updating  with example